# How to put wildcard string in URL using Regex PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a url:
    http://domain.com/home/audio/14/1/file.mp3

But the strings inside the last to sub directories could be different, such as:

```
http://domain.com/home/audio/142/14/file.mp3 or 
http://domain.com/home/audio/67/424/file.mp3
```

The formatting # of sub directories will be the same, but I need to be able to get the file.mp3 regardless of what the /xx/xx/ has. I'm trying to build a Regex in PHP to accommodate this, some kind of wildcard in place of the characters that could be in those sub directories. Something like:

http://domain.com/home/audio/[wildcardregexhere]/[wildcardregexhere]/file.mp3

Sorry, I've never done Regex before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking: do you want to rewrite the incoming requests on the server side or are you looking for some magical URL to use on the client side that somehow tries all available combinations to download content?

Comment: Is this question attempting to validate the string or extract a portion of the string? This detail is crucial.

Comment: ugh, this was 3 years ago, I can't recall the exact use case for this, but I think it was a situation where the last two directories before the `file.mp3` was randomized (I was probably trying to scrape some site TBH). I think the answer below got me to the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities, one is to match all characters instead of slash `/`. How will you express this? Like `[^\/]*`. In the brackets you list all chars, that should match, but with `^` at start you negate the list. So you want to match other than slash (you have to escape it, so we use `\/` instead of single `/`). And with the asterisk we say, that there could be zero, one or a lot of characters other than slash - its the wildcard you are looking for.

So how will the whole regexp look like?

```
http:\/\/domain.com\/home\/audio\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/.*\.mp3
```

I guess, that `file` could any match, so I used `.*`.
In perl or php syntax it will be like:

```
/http:\/\/domain.com\/home\/audio\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/.*\.mp3/
```

In Java you have to double quote (escape the escape character backslash `\\`).

Good luck!